# Logarithmic table

Tags: r, logarithm

I'm trying to create table. But special one. It should be like this:

[image: Logarithmic table]

It shows logarithm base 10, where anyone could find solution. Simply it's logarithmic table.
I know, I could do it manually number by number, but it should be done better, I think.
It's possible, that I should use function `sapply()` or something similar, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! To help people answer your question please explain what you want this table to show. It's not obvious what the table you've linked to shows, and not everybody can access external sites, and sometimes link break.

Comment: I think we can start with `round(log10(11),4)` = 1.0414 (the second entry in the first column is 0.0414).

Comment: So then I should do logii=c(round(log10(10:50),4)) and logii=logii-1

Comment: @maydin, please post your comment as an answer ... (and maybe give an explanation ...)

Comment: and then if I look to other columns, there is always added certain number in one row.

Comment: So then I do *10000 to delete 0. and somehow add 0 at the begining of number everywhere, where I've got less then 4 digits.

Comment: Then I name col and row: rownames(logous) <- c(10:50)
colnames(logous) <- c(0:9)

Comment: or if `m` is your previous result you could do `gsub("^0\\.","",sprintf("%0.4f",m))`

Comment: I think you should go ahead and put all of the pieces together to post an answer to your own question (this is encouraged)

Comment: Thank you so much! There's little work to do (I think I know how) at the right side of table. I'l do it by rep() maybe.

Comment: Just curious: what is your ultimate goal?  It's a little surprising to me that people are still working with log tables ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure, it should be shorter, but it works:

```
#I'll do left side like a matrix, delete everything not needed (I left 4 rounded decimals digits
logous <- matrix((round(log(seq(10,50.9,0.1),10)-1,4)*10000),ncol=10,byrow=T)


rownames(logous) <- c(10:50)#name rows
colnames(logous) <- c(0:9)#name columns

#sprintf("%04.0f", logous) 
#instead of that above, I'll do formatC() to have everywhere 4 digits
formatC(logous, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0")

logous <- cbind(logous, md1=c(4, 4, rep(x=3, each=5, times=1), rep(x=2, each=12, times=1), rep(x=1, each=22, times=1)), 
                        md2=c(8, 8, 7, rep(x=(6:5), each=3, times=1), rep(x=4, each=6, times=1), rep(x=3, each=10, times=1), rep(x=2, each=16, times=1)),
                        md3=c(12:10, 10:8, 8, rep(x=7, each=3, times=1), rep(x=6, each=4, times=1), rep(x=5, each=5, times=1), rep(x=4, each=8, times=1), rep(x=3, each=14, times=1)),
                        md4=c(17, 15:11, 11:9, 9, rep(x=8, each=3, times=1), rep(x=7, each=4, times=1), rep(x=6, each=5, times=1), rep(x=5, each=7, times=1), rep(x=4, each=11, times=1), 3),
                        md5=c(21, 19, 17:13, rep(x=12:10, each=2, times=1), rep(x=9:8, each=3, times=1), rep(x=7, each=4, times=1), rep(x=6, each=6, times=1), rep(x=5, each=9, times=1), rep(x=4, each=3, times=1)),
                        md6=c(25, 23, 21, 19:14, rep(x=13:10, each=2, times=1), rep(x=9:8, each=4, times=1), rep(x=7, each=5, times=1), rep(x=6, each=7, times=1), rep(x=5, each=4, times=1)),
                        md7=c(29, 26, 24, 23, 21, 20, 18:16, 16:14, 14:12, 12, rep(x=11:10, each=3, times=1), rep(x=9, each=4, times=1), rep(x=8, each=5, times=1), rep(x=7, each=6, times=1), rep(x=6, each=4, times=1)),
                        md8=c(33, 30, 28, 26, 24, 22:16,  rep(x=15:12, each=2, times=1), rep(x=11, each=3, times=1), rep(x=10:9, each=4, times=1), rep(x=8:7, each=5, times=1)),
                        md9=c(37, 34, 31, 29, 27, 25:24, 22:17, 17:16, rep(x=15:13, each=2, times=1), rep(x=12:11, each=3, times=1), rep(x=10, each=4, times=1), rep(x=9:8, each=5, times=1)))  

#I added new columns, maybe it could be shorter and easier, but this works

logous #see my result
```

Uff! That's it!

Comment: If the *meaning* of the "mean difference" columns was clearer (are these error bounds?) they might be computable in a simpler way ...

Comment: You can *almost* get the mean difference columns as follows: `vals <- matrix(seq(10, 50.9, 0.1), ncol=10, byrow = TRUE); m <- log10(vals); sapply(1:9,  function(i) round(rowMeans(log10(vals+i/10)-m)*1000))`.  These are off by 1 digit from the printed table in some places.

Comment: Well, one other thing, how could I color my headerbackground?

Comment: Well, it appears to be something else Ben Bolker, I look at the bottom of table and there are numbers like 50 and so on. But really thank you! It's almost done, the last is to color header.